# Determine number of days between dates

Tags: vba, datediff

How do I get the whole date difference in VBA?

I know that to get the year or the month or the day I do:

```
DateDiff("yyyy", Me.DateofBirth, Me.Year).
```

I want the whole difference. Not just the year, and the two columns that I have are *Date of Birth* and *Year*.

Comment: Check here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) or here (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php).

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored internally in VBA as doubles, with the integer portion as the number of days since 1/1/1900. To get the difference between two dates, you can just subtract them:

```
Dim dob As Date
dob = DateSerial(1990, 1, 1)

Dim difference As Date
difference = Now - dob

Debug.Print Year(difference) - 1900 & " years, " & _
            Month(difference) & " months, " & _
            Day(difference) & " days."
```

If you want the total number of days, you can just subtract them and use the numeric value of the underlying double:

```
Dim dob As Date
dob = DateSerial(1990, 1, 1)

Dim days As Long
days = Now - dob
Debug.Print days & " days."
```